# Position relative to bottom + container height

Tags: html, css

I´m builnding a dropdown menu using flexbox. Considering the following code, how can I make the Links appear bellow the buttom, not above it ?

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="dropdown-item">
        Link 1
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="dropdown-item">
        Link 1
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="dropdown-item">
        Link 1
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #34becd;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0gnL4u2f/)

Comment: top:100% instead of bottom:0

Comment: beside that top: 100%, use UL LI instead of div, and you don't need to use `<div class="dropdown-item"></div>`. the item can be simply `a` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `.dropdown-content`, you need to replace `bottom: 0px;` with `top: 100%;`.

Updated example from your fiddle:

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #34becd;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="dropdown-item">
        Link 1
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="dropdown-item">
        Link 1
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="dropdown-item">
        Link 1
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```